# Is it safe to use npm install with --force on production?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, npm-install

we are facing an interesting problem in our build server that prevents our app to install npm dependencies which causes most of our builds to fail.

We are using the build server **Visual Studio Team Services** which runs Windows. When we are trying to install npm dependencies we get the following error:

```
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0931743Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0931743Z npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0941742Z npm ERR! node v0.12.7
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0941742Z npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0951737Z npm ERR! path C:\NPM\Cache\repeating\1.1.3\package\package.json
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0951737Z npm ERR! code EPERM
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0951737Z npm ERR! errno -4048
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0981746Z npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\NPM\Cache\repeating\1.1.3\package\package.json'
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0991748Z npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.0991748Z npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\NPM\Cache\repeating\1.1.3\package\package.json']
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1001741Z npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1001741Z npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1011746Z npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\NPM\\Cache\\repeating\\1.1.3\\package\\package.json',
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1011746Z npm ERR!   parent: 'babel-traverse' }
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1021741Z npm ERR! 
    2016-04-13T12:44:25.1021741Z npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    2016-04-13T12:44:28.0020021Z npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2016-04-13T12:44:28.0029943Z npm ERR!     C:\a\1\s\src\OrderEze.Web\npm-debug.log
    2016-04-13T12:44:28.1069958Z ##[debug]rc:4294963248
    2016-04-13T12:44:28.1079955Z Npm failed with error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 4294963248
```

We found that if we try to install our dependencies using the force command, everything works fine:

```
npm install --force
```

My question is simple. Will we have any issues with this configuration? Why npm warns us about this command? Any idea can help :)

Comment: I've same question

Comment: did you find out the answer?